# Solving recurrences with iteration, substitution, Master Theorem?

Tags: algorithm, math, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I'm familiar with solving recurrences with iteration:

```
t(1) = c1
t(2) = t(1) + c2 = c1 + c2
t(3) = t(2) + c2 = c1 + 2c2
...
t(n) = c1 + (n-1)c2 = O(n)
```

But what if I had a recurrence with no base case? How would I solve it using the three methods mentioned in the title?

```
t(n) = 2t(n/2) + 1
```

For Master Theorem I know the first step, find `a`, `b`, and `f(n)`:

```
a = 2
b = 2
f(n) = 1
```

But not where to go from here. I'm at a standstill because I'm not sure how to approach the question.

Comment: So which way do you want to know how to do it?

Comment: All three so I can understand each method better.

Comment: I appreciate it! I'm new to asymptotics for recurrences; it's not as simple as analysis of algorithms.

Comment: Let me know if it helped you.  The master theorem you stated in your question is generalized for any f(n).  I used what I did because it worked for this problem.  But if you an f(n) that was not in form of n^c you would need to use a more generalized form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of 2 ways to solve this:

```
(1) T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1
(2) T(n/2) = 2T(n/4) + 1
now replace T(n/2) from (2) into (1)

T(n) = 2[2T(n/4) + 1] + 1
     = 2^2T(n/4) + 2 + 1

T(n/4) = 2T(n/8) + 1
T(n) = 2^2[2T(n/8) + 1] + 2 + 1
     = 2^3T(n/8) + 4 + 2 + 1
```

You would just keep doing this until you can generalize.  Eventually you will spot that:

```
T(n) = 2^kT(n/2^k) + sum(2^(k-1))
```

You want T(1) so set n/2^k = 1 and solve for k. When you do this you will find that, k = lgn

Substitute lgn for k you will end up with

```
T(n) = 2^lgnT(n/2^lgn) + (1 - 2^lgn) / (1 - 2)
2^lgn = n so,

T(n) = nT(1) + n - 1
T(n) = n + n - 1 where n is the dominant term.
```

For Master Theorem its really fast

```
Consider, T(n) = aT(n/b) + n^c for n>1
```

There are three cases (note that b is the log base)

```
(1)  if logb a < c, T(n)=Θ(n^c),

(2)  if logb a = c, T (n) = Θ(n^c log n),

(3)  if logb a > c, T(n) = Θ(n^(logb a)).
```

In this case a = 2, b = 2, and c = 0 (n^0 = 1)

A quick check shows case 3.

```
n^(log2 2)

note log2 2 is 1

So by master theorem this is Θ(n)
```

Comment: Thank you, you really cleared it up. The textbook I'm using does MT a different way which at first glance is a little more confusing. Yours is succinct, thanks!

Comment: @gator That MT you see in the book is definitely generalized.  I ran into the same issue.  Start here and build to where f(n) is a function not in the form n^c.  If you get stuck reply here and I'll help you with that one too.  Good luck

Comment: One last thing; can you clarify how you went from `T(n) = 2^k...` to `T(n) = n + logn`?

Comment: @gator, sure I will edit the post in a few minutes to explain it at that part

Comment: @gator, you were correct to question where the logn came from.  Because it was a mistake.  sum(2^k-1) is geometric so you can calculate the sum with a general formula.  Good catch.  I fixed it in the post

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the Master Theorem, the Recursion Tree Method and the Iterative Method there is also the so
called "Substitution Method".

Often you will find people talking about the
substitution method, when in fact they mean the iterative method (especially on Youtube).
I guess this stems from the fact that in the iterative method you are also substituting
something, namely the `n+1`-th recursive call into the `n`-th one...

The standard reference work about algorithms 
([CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)) 
defines it as follows:

> #### Substitution Method
>
> 1. Guess the form of the solution.
> 2. Use mathematical induction to find the constants and show that the solution works.

As example let's take your recurrence equation: `T(n) = 2T(ⁿ/₂)+1`

We guess that the solution is `T(n) ∈ O(n²)`, so we have to prove that 
`T(n) ≤ cn²` for some constant `c`.
Also, let's assume that for `n=1` you are doing some constant work `c`.

**Given:**

```
T(1) ≤ c
T(n) = 2T(ⁿ/₂)+1
```

**To prove:**

```
∃c > 0, ∃n₀ ∈ ℕ, ∀n ≥ n₀, such that T(n) ≤ cn² is true.
```

**Base Case:**

```
n=1:  T(1) ≤ c    
n=2:  T(2) ≤ T(1) + T(1) + 1 ≤ 4c
             (≤c)   (≤c)      (cn²)
```

**Induction Step:**

As inductive hypothesis we assume `T(n) ≤ cn²` for all positive numbers smaller than `n`
especially for `(ⁿ/₂)`.

Therefore `T(ⁿ/₂) ≤ c(ⁿ/₂)²`, and hence

```
T(n) ≤ 2c(ⁿ/₂)² + 1     ⟵ Here we're substituting c(ⁿ/₂)² for T(ⁿ/₂)
     = (¹/₂)cn² + 1
     ≤ cn²  (for c ≥ 2, and all n ∈ ℕ)
```

So we have shown, that there is a constant `c`, such that `T(n) ≤ cn²` is true for all `n ∈ ℕ`.
This means exactly `T(n) ∈ O(n²)`. ∎

(for Ω, and hence Θ, the proof is similar).